# Usage of ffmpeg geq options

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images

I am trying to overlay a transparent image in the video using ffmpeg. I found

`geq=g='g(X,Y)':a='0.3*alpha(X,Y)'`

for changing the transparency of the image. I know it changes the image transparency based on the decimal multiplied. I want to know

1. Need of g='g(X,Y)'. I am getting *A luminance or RGB expression is mandatory* if I remove that.
2. What is the value of X and Y. As per documentation *The coordinates of the current sample.* https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#geq

The full command I am using if it needed

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i img.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=50:50,geq=g='g(X,Y)':a='0.3*alpha(X,Y)'[unni];[0][unni]overlay=W-w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" out.mp4
```

It also works with `geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.3*alpha(X,Y)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X and Y don't refer to any specific pixel co-ordinates. The geq filter operates upon all pixels of a video frame, one at a time. They are variables which represent the co-ordinates of the current pixel being evaluated.

The geq filter can operate upon pixels encoded as either RGB or YUV. But the actual code used is different, so it needs to know which type. In order to signal that the input is RGB, at least one of R G or B expressions should be set. For YUV, Y (luminance) expr should be set. You can simply set the value to identity (`p(X,Y)`).

Comment: geq filter command requires a luminance expression. It does not require RGB expression. ```ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i 50x50-icon-0.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=50:50,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='0.3*alpha(X,Y)'[unni];[0][unni]overlay=W-w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" out.mp4``` works. Not sure why it needs that as RGB/YUV can be detected from source.

Comment: It requires *one* of the two. It doesn't detect source type directly because it will request a pixel format conversion from the filter framework based on the expression provided.

Answer (score 2):

`g='g(X,Y)'` or `r='r(X,Y)'` statements don't do anything but they're required by the filter, for RGB colorspace. They basically set the green/red value to current green/red value of the pixel, for all pixels of the input.

`alpha(X,Y)` takes the current alpha value of each coordinate, pixel by pixel. Then you multiply that by `0.3` to make it more transparent.